# Quartzmon / Quartzmin not detecting services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, quartz.net

Currently, i am developing a task scheduler projects using quartz with .net 6. However, i don't have enough time and knowledge to develop a UI for management tools. After searching some article i found this: [Quartzmin](https://github.com/jlucansky/Quartzmin), a management tools for quartz. and a fork of that Quartzmon is compatible with .net core.

So i tried implementing it with my projects but i found a problem, The QuartzJob cannot run with Registered Service.

Program.cs

```
var buildConfig = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

buildConfig.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(config =>
{
    config.ConfigureServices(service =>
    {
        service.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();

        service.AddQuartzmon();
    });

    config.Configure(app =>
    {
        var scheduler = Scheduler.Create().Result;

        app.UseQuartzmon(new QuartzmonOptions()
        {
            Scheduler = scheduler,
            VirtualPathRoot = "/Quartzmon",
            UseLocalTime = true
        });
    });
});

var builder = buildConfig.Build();

await builder.RunAsync();
```

Scheduler & Job

```
public static class Scheduler
{
    public static async Task<IScheduler> Create()
    {
        var scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<RepoJob>.StoreDurably().Build();
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(sc => sc.WithIntervalInMinutes(5)).Build();

        await scheduler.Schedule(job, trigger);
        await scheduler.Start();

        return scheduler;
    }
}

public class RepoJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo;

    public RepoJob(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("This is a Test Job");

        // Do Logic Repository Work
        // repo.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

When i start the application however nothing happens. but when i create a parameter less constructor for the RepoJob and run the application it run the execute function. But this causes the repo object to be null since it is not instantiated.

This is a bit confusing since i have registered it in the service configuration.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dependency injection problem :/
By default, Quartz has no knowledge of the .NET dependency injection container and will not be able to resolve services from it. This means that when Quartz tries to instantiate the RepoJob class, it is unable to resolve the IRepository dependency, hence it fails silently.

To fix this, you can try to integrate Quartz with the .NET dependency injection system. This will enable Quartz to resolve its jobs and their dependencies from the container.

Try modifying the Program.cs to use Quartz with DI, like in this example:

```
var buildConfig = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

buildConfig.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(config =>
{
    config.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IRepository, Repository>();

        // Add Quartz services
        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            // Register the job, setting it up to inject IRepository
            q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();
            var jobKey = new JobKey("RepoJobKey");
            q.AddJob<RepoJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));
            q.AddTrigger(t => t
                .WithIdentity("RepoTrigger")
                .ForJob(jobKey)
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMinutes(5))
            );
        });

        services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
        {
            options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
        });

        services.AddQuartzmon();
    });

    config.Configure(app =>
    {
        var scheduler = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IScheduler>();

        app.UseQuartzmon(new QuartzmonOptions()
        {
            Scheduler = scheduler,
            VirtualPathRoot = "/Quartzmon",
            UseLocalTime = true
        });
    });
});

var builder = buildConfig.Build();

await builder.RunAsync();
```

Oh! Ensure you have the Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection package installed. This package provides extensions to integrate Quartz with .NET's built-in dependency injection. -> dotnet add package Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection

I Hope it works!